# Is it possible to have a table-like display for the options in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

Essentially I would like to show options within the JComboBox that have one or two variables of additional information associated with them and I would like to show the user that information in a more structured way than just e.g. appending them.

In other words, I would like the options in the JComboBox to look like this:

```
John Smith     Male    01/01/1980
Jane Harrison  Female  01/01/1980
```

What I do NOT want is to simply append all the information so that it would look like this:

```
John Smith (Male, 01/01/1980)
Jane Harrison (Female, 01/01/1980)
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate but it seems to me that most questions with the keywords JComboBox and table are about the "opposite" problem, i.e. putting a JComboBox within a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for a completely different solution in the end but thought that this answer might eventually benefit somebody.

You can essentially design the look of the options in the `JComboBox` yourself by using a `ListCellRenderer`. See this crude example:

```
String[][] ar = {{"aasdf","ff"},{"fd","werewfewf"}};
JComboBox<String[]> box = new JComboBox<>(ar);
box.setRenderer(new TableListCellRenderer());
getContentPane().add(box,BorderLayout.NORTH); // You can add it wherever you want
```

This is the class for the `TableListCellRenderer`:

```
class TableListCellRenderer
implements ListCellRenderer<String[]>
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String[]> list,
                                               String[] value,
                                               int index,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JPanel ret = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        ret.add(new JLabel(value[0]));
        ret.add(new JLabel(value[1]));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

See below for a screenshot. You can see that there are some flaws that would need to be resolved before you can use this in practice, but most of those can probably be resolved by playing around with the layout of the JPanel.

[image: Screenshot of example]

For further information, see [the tutorial page on the JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) and [the javadoc on the ListCellRenderer interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) (which contains a helpful simple example that).